# Custom `TabScrollButton` for `Tabs` component in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

The Tabs API of Material UI [mentions](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#props) that you can provide your own ScrollButtonComponent in order to render customized scroll buttons. However there is no real clear documentation on the specific of what this ScrollButtonComponent should look like.

I have found the [native implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/TabScrollButton.js) on the Material UI git repository, I guess this could be used to establish what is required, however that feels a little bit of a hack especially since this component is marked as 'private'.

Is there something that I'm missing on the topic, or would taking a look at the native implementation the "the way to go"?

Comment: What element do you want to use instead of the default one? Can you provide some code in order to proper see what the situation is how to help you

Comment: @Sabbin I just want some minor customization of existing behaviour. I can get a custom component up and running using the original code as inspiration (even though it is marked as private and not exported globally). However I found it a bit odd that the MUI documentation API mentioned you can provide your own component but without specifying what it should look like (passed props, etc.). It just feels that documentation on that part is missing.